# Calculate the gamma function in a program

Tags: gamma-function, programming

I am currently trying to implement the gamma function in a program I am writing. I know that the gamma function is:
$$\Gamma(\alpha) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha - 1}e^{-x}\text{ d}x$$

However, I do not know what the $\int$, the ${x}$, and the ${d}$ are supposed to stand for.

I know that you can do it quite easily with positive integers like this:

$$\Gamma(\alpha) = (a -1)!$$
How would I go about implementing that into a program for numbers other than positive integers?

Comment: If you do not know what the $\int$ and $d$ signs represent, it will be difficult to implement a program! See the Wikipedia article on the Gamma function for a list of approximations which could be adapted to a computer program

Comment: Best to find an existing implementation. Alternatively, look up the Lanczos algorithm.

Comment: @martycohen I would take an existing implementation if there were one. I'm doing the entire thing in a language that barely any people use. I might have to look deeper into what other people did in other languages.

Comment: Off topic for this stack:  Why not wrap an implementation in one of these other languages with a shim in your target language?

Comment: Here is discussion and implementaqtion:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_approximation#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lanczos%20approximation,gamma%20function%20with%20fixed%20precision.

Comment: You can check this website: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @EricTowers I could call the python `math.gamma()`-function from the command line, but I want to distribute the code I'm writing. Saying: `For this library you need an entirely different programming language` doesn't sound like good advertisement for my extension/library.

Comment: "I'm doing the entire thing in a language that barely any people use." is not good advertisement for sinking large amounts of time re-implementing a wheel readily available in languages that *do* have large mind share.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to take a look at [SymPy's implementation of the Gamma Function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html):

[image]

The full implementation considers numerical integral arguments, half-integral values and it is publicly available at [this GitHub Page](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/00d6469eafdd4aac346a0b598184c15f2560dbe5/sympy/functions/special/gamma_functions.py#L28-L211).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't seem to implement the code since they used `arg.p` and `arg.q` which I don't understand and both of which are not documented. Do you know that they are or did you just recommend it to me?

Comment: For a rational number, in this context, $p$ is the numerator part and $q$ the denominator part.